# Use of move_uploaded_file() function issue

Tags: php, web-hosting

I have hosted my website to my server.The website is functioning well as same as the localhost.However,When i try to move uploaded files to the uploads folder,the move_uploaded_file() function is not working as it is working with the localhost.On using the mysql_error() function to find the error,it is not giving me any results.What is the problem with my code

code one is not giving me any results
**code 1**

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Upfile']['tmp_name'],$location.$_FILES['Upfile']['name'])){
 echo'proceed';
}else{
echo mysql_error();
}
```

code two is outputing  the else phrase
echo'cannot move file to folder';
code 2

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Upfile']['tmp_name'],$location.$_FILES['Upfile']['name'])){
 echo'proceed';
}else{
echo 'cannot move file to folder ';
}
```

Comment: Check folder permissions for your destination

Comment: `mysql_error()` is only useful for getting errors about mysql (i.e. other functions whose names begin with `mysql_`).

Comment: And how to go about this please

Comment: At first, mysql_error() is not good to catch error of moving file.
second, If your host is linux, remember that linux is case-sensitive about directory and files. so "upload_dir" is different to "upload_Dir".

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the second parameter i.e destination where you are storing the uploaded file should be in string format.